# How to configure RxJS5 typings in WebStorm 2016.1 for added Observable methods?

Tags: webstorm, rxjs5

I am trying to configure WebStorm to correctly type-hint RxJS 5, but it's not picking up methods on `Observable`:

[image]

You can see that both `.of()` and `.map()` are "unresolved." The code executes as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: Try 2016.1.1  version -- some stuff was fixed there (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20865). If still issues -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20992

Comment: Thanks. Looks like JetBrains is on it. :)